# Set metadata to specific extensions in gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm trying to set metadata using gsutil to specific extensions (html,js,css).

Is there any way to do it with a regex or something? now I have this, which obviously works, but is not that nice:

```
gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control:no-transform, public, max-age=86400" gs://bucket-name/**.js
gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control:no-transform, public, max-age=86400" gs://bucket-name/**.html
gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control:no-transform, public, max-age=86400" gs://bucket-name/**.css
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use shell comma syntax to make it somewhat more succinct:

```
gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control:no-transform, public, max-age=86400" gs://bucket-name/**.{js,html,css}
```

Note that the shell turns this into

```
gs://bucket-name/**.js gs://bucket-name/**.html gs://bucket-name/**.css
```

and then gsutil expands the `**` wildcards.